# ¿Cómo calcular la cantidad de horas pasadas entre la hora de un día a una hora del día siguiente en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

sucede que quiero calcular la cantidad de horas transcurridas desde las 11:00 p.m. del día 4 de octubre 2021 hasta la 1:00 a.m. del día 5 de octubre 2021, suponiendo que quiero saber cuantas horas tiene adelantada un determinado equipo que tiene desfase, fácilmente nosotros podemos saber que de 11pm a 1am del siguiente día hay 2 horas de diferencia, pero el código que yo utilizo me arroja que hay -20 horas, cosa que esta mal. Es que quiero hacer un programa que calcule los años, meses, días y horas de diferencia entre la hora actual vs equipos con tiempo atrasado y equipos con tiempo adelantado, pero el problema se presenta es cuando quiero calcular la cantidad de tiempo adelantado en las hora, si tiene un mejor código que cumpla con todo les agradezco. abajo verán la parte del código que uso para calcular el adelanto de tiempo que exista en algún equipo.

```
         {
            DateTime PRIMERO_LOCAL = DTP_FECHA_LOCAL.Value.Date + 
            DateTime DTP_HORA_LOCAL.Value.TimeOfDay; //es la hora local

            DateTime SEGUNDO_DVR = DTP_FECHA_DVR.Value.Date + DTP_HORA_DVR.Value.TimeOfDay; // es la hora del cualquier equipo que tiene tiempo adelantado.

            TimeSpan TS_DIF = SEGUNDO_DVR - PRIMERO_LOCAL;;

            int INT_DIF_AÑOS = SEGUNDO_DVR.Year - PRIMERO_LOCAL.Year;
            int INT_DIF_MESES = SEGUNDO_DVR.Month - PRIMERO_LOCAL.Month;
            int INT_DIF_DIAS = SEGUNDO_DVR.DayOfYear - PRIMERO_LOCAL.DayOfYear;
            int INT_DIF_HORAS = SEGUNDO_DVR.Hour - PRIMERO_LOCAL.Hour; // cuando pasa de un dia para otro la hora no da exacta
            int INT_DIF_MINUTOS = SEGUNDO_DVR.Minute - PRIMERO_LOCAL.Minute;
            int INT_DIF_SEGUNDOS = SEGUNDO_DVR.Second - PRIMERO_LOCAL.Second;

            LBL_AÑOS.Text = "Años: " + INT_DIF_AÑOS;
            LBL_MESES.Text = "Meses: " + INT_DIF_MESES;
            LBL_DIAS.Text = "Dias: " + INT_DIF_DIAS;
            LBL_HORAS.Text = "Horas: " + INT_DIF_HORAS;
            LBL_MINUTOS.Text = "Minutos: " + INT_DIF_MINUTOS;
            LBL_SEGUNDOS.Text = "Segundos: " + INT_DIF_SEGUNDOS;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net tiene herramientas bastante potentes para el manejo de fechas e intervalos, no es necesario hacerlo de forma manual.

En este caso, si quieres saber la diferencia entre dos fechas, lo único que necesitas es restar una de la otra, lo que te da un objeto de tipo `TimeSpan`.

Una vez tenemos la diferencia de fechas, como lo que quieres es saber las horas totales de diferencia que tienes, puedes acceder a la propiedad `TotalHours` de `TimeSpan` y obtener el resultado que buscas.

Te pongo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
//Definimos las fechas a restar
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
DateTime fecha=DateTime.ParseExact("04/10/2021 23:00:00","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider);
DateTime fecha2=DateTime.ParseExact("05/10/2021 01:00:00","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider);

//Las restamos y obtenemos TotalHours del resultado
var horas=(fecha2-fecha).TotalHours;
//nos devuelve 2, como esperabamos.
Console.WriteLine(horas);
```